# I keep getting this error: type error: int object not iterable error when i try to run this. i dont seem to understand why

Tags: python-2.7, iterable

```
def calculate_tax(income_input):
  income_inpu = {}
  for item in income_input:
    tax = '0'
    income = income_input[item]      
    if income in range(0, 1001):
      tax = (0*income)
    if income in range(1001, 10001):
      tax = (0.1 * (income-1000))
    if income in range(10001, 20201):
      tax = ((0.1*(10000-1000)) + (0.15*(income-10000)))
    if income in range(20201, 30751):
      tax = ((0.1*(10000-1000)) + (0.15*(20200-10000)) + (0.2*(income-20200)))
    if income in range(30751, 50001):
      tax = ((0.1*(10000-1000)) + (0.15*(20200-10000)) + (0.2*(30750-20200)) + (0.25*(income-30750)))
    if (income > 50000):
      tax = ((0.1*(10000-1000)) + (0.15*(20200-10000)) + (0.2*(30750-20200)) + (0.25*(50000-30750)) + (0.3*(income-50000)))            
    income_inpu[item] = tax
  return income_inpu
```

Comment: I assume that `income_inpu = {}` is a typo and should be `income_input = {}`. If so, then why do you reassign it to an empty dictionary if you receive it as a function argument? If not then you should create an smaller and cleaner example, with better variable names.

Comment: I am trying to write a function that will take as an argument, a dictionary containing key-value pairs of people's names as the keys and their yearly incomes as the values.
The function is mearnt to return a dictionary containing key-value pairs of the same people’s names as keys and their yearly tax bill as the values. did i do this right? am actually new to programming. Thanks

Comment: This code runs ok and doesn't produce any exceptions when. What value are you passing as `income_input`?

Comment: The soln is tested accordng to the codes below:

Comment: from unittest import TestCase

class CalculateTaxTests(TestCase):
  def test_it_calculates_tax_for_one_person(self):
    result = calculate_tax({"James": 20500})
    self.assertEqual(result, {"James": 2490.0}, msg="Should return {'James': 2490.0} for the input {'James': 20500}")

Comment: def test_it_calculates_tax_for_several_people(self):
    income_input = {"James": 20500, "Mary": 500, "Evan": 70000}
    result = calculate_tax(income_input)
    self.assertEqual({"James": 2490.0, "Mary": 0, "Evan": 15352.5}, result,
      msg="Should return {} for the input {}".format(
            {"James": 2490.0, "Mary": 0, "Evan": 15352.5},
            {"James": 20500, "Mary": 500, "Evan": 70000}
      )
    )

Comment: def test_it_does_not_accept_integers(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as context:
      calculate_tax(1)
      self.assertEqual(
        "The provided input is not a dictionary.",
        context.exception.message, "Invalid input of type int not allowed"
      )

Comment: def test_calculated_tax_is_a_float(self):
    result = calculate_tax({"Jane": 20500})
    self.assertIsInstance(
      calculate_tax({"Jane": 20500}), dict, msg="Should return a result of data type dict")
    self.assertIsInstance(result["Jane"], float, msg="Tax returned should be an float.")

Comment: def test_it_returns_zero_tax_for_income_less_than_1000(self):
    result = calculate_tax({"Jake": 100})
    self.assertEqual(result, {"Jake": 0}, msg="Should return zero tax for incomes less than 1000")

  def test_it_throws_an_error_if_any_of_the_inputs_is_non_numeric(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError, msg='Allow only numeric input'):
      calculate_tax({"James": 2490.0, "Kiura": '200', "Kinuthia": 15352.5})

Comment: def test_it_return_an_empty_dict_for_an_empty_dict_input(self):
    result = calculate_tax({})
    self.assertEqual(result, {}, msg='Should return an empty dict if the input was an empty dict')